# How to capture screen image with mouse pointer on it in Java

Tags: java, screen, capture

How to capture screen image with mouse pointer on it in Java? In know that i can capture screen with Robot class, but it captures screen without mouse pointer on it, so this is not an solution for me.

Comment: Um, you mean OS? Windows Vista. This matters?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. Java is platform independent.

Comment: @BalusC is correct, but some platforms have convenient tools, e.g. _Grab.app_ on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's not directly possible, but you can use [`MouseInfo#getPointerInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html#getPointerInfo%28%29) to get information where the pointer is currently located.

```
int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;
```

After getting the screenshot as `BufferedImage`, you can place your own cursor image at exactly that location on the screenshot with help of Java 2D API.

```
Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage screenCapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screen);

Image cursor = ImageIO.read(new File("c:/cursor.gif"));
int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;
int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;

Graphics2D graphics2D = screenCapture.createGraphics();
graphics2D.drawImage(cursor, x, y, 16, 16, null); // cursor.gif is 16x16 size.
ImageIO.write(screenCapture, "GIF", new File("c:/capture.gif"));
```

Comment: This doesn't save the actual cursor, just a placeholder cursor from file. If my cursor is different (hand cursor, drag cursor, resize cursors, no cursor at all, custom cursor pack in control panel), then it breaks.

Comment: @Zom-B: As answered, that's not directly possible. So this is really your best bet which should be sufficient if your sole interest is the cursor position. If you know a better solution, feel free to post it :)

Comment: 1. it doesn't answer the original question, it just gives something that approaches it. 2. I'm looking into this because I want to detect if the display is fullscreen (alternatively whenever the mouse is hidden even if not fullscreen), but this appears a dead end.

Comment: @Zom-B: As answered, **that's not directly possible**. What follows thereafter was the "best alternative" the OP could get. Oneliner answers like "No that's not possible." aren't my style. Again, if you know a better solution, feel free to post it :)

Comment: What does gif of the cursor, which can be different for different items? In the text box, the cursor is text cursor, on a hyperlink cursor "hand" ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Native Access in order to access operating system specific mouse cursors/pointers dynamically.

Comment: Where you able to fix this issue ? could you give us more details about the solution ?