# Capture screen with mouse pointer using xuggler

Tags: java, xuggle

following is the code to capture screen and make video from it using xuggler and it is working fine, but the generated video does not have mouse cursor in it. I also want to capture mouse pointer to show the mouse activity.

Can some one guide me on this.

```
package com.test.video;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;

public class ScreenRecordingExample {

    private static final double FRAME_RATE = 5;

    private static final int SECONDS_TO_RUN_FOR = 120;

    private static final String outputFilename = "c:/mydesktop.mp4";

    private static Dimension screenBounds;

    private static Graphics2D imageGraphics;

    public static Image m_MouseIcon = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // let's make a IMediaWriter to write the file.
        final IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename);

        screenBounds = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // We tell it we're going to add one video stream, with id 0,
        // at position 0, and that it will have a fixed frame rate of FRAME_RATE.
        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4, screenBounds.width/2, screenBounds.height/2);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        try {
            m_MouseIcon = ImageIO.read(ScreenRecordingExample.class.getResource("resource/captionMouseIcon.png"));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < SECONDS_TO_RUN_FOR * FRAME_RATE; index++) {

            // take the screen shot
            BufferedImage screen = getDesktopScreenshot();

            // convert to the right image type
            BufferedImage bgrScreen = convertToType(screen, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

            // encode the image to stream #0
            writer.encodeVideo(0, bgrScreen, System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

            // sleep for frame rate milliseconds
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / FRAME_RATE));
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }

        }

        // tell the writer to close and write the trailer if  needed
        writer.close();

    }

    public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage sourceImage, int targetType) {

        BufferedImage image;

        // if the source image is already the target type, return the source image
        if (sourceImage.getType() == targetType) {
            image = sourceImage;
        }
        // otherwise create a new image of the target type and draw the new image
        else {
            image = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), targetType);
            image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
        }

        return image;

    }

    private static BufferedImage getDesktopScreenshot() {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(screenBounds);
            return robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
        } 
        catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Here's the example code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962271/how-to-capture-screen-image-with-mouse-pointer-on-it-in-java/2962377#2962377

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` to obtain the current position of the pointer.  Draw a 'close facsimile of'(1) the pointer at that `Point` on the `BufferedImage`.

---

1) For [Screenshooter](http://pscode.org/screenshooter/), I use a GIF image of a pointer.

Comment: this will not give the dynamic cursor type while taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Native Access(JNA) in order to retrieve OS specific mouse cursor type in real time and then extract its image from system file(user32.dll in windows) and overlay on the screen shot.

Comment: Where you able to fix this issue ? could you give us more details about the solution ?