# How to get the current mouse cursor type in java?

Tags: java, screenshot, screen-capture, mouse-cursor

While taking a screen shot in java the mouse cursor does not appear. I am drawing the mouse cursor on the screen shot.

How to know which image of the cursor to draw depending on its state? (busy, moving over text, placed on a link, etc)

Comment: How are you taking the screen shot? Getting the cursor as well is usually an option on most screen grabbing programs.

Comment: i am gettin it through java Robot class using the function createScreenCapture()

Comment: Check out this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962271/how-to-capture-screen-image-with-mouse-pointer-on-it-in-java

Comment: how do i know which mouse image to draw out of the following as shown in the link... http://www.google.com/imgres?q=mouse+cursor&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=664&tbm=isch&tbnid=8KtCIOXrYF82PM:&imgrefurl=http://www.blogiseverything.com/freebies/vista-aero-cursors-for-xp/&docid=agkH9Aj5E153WM&w=306&h=296&ei=41E7Tv6GFoi8rAfM2ZmPBQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=930&vpy=116&dur=647&hovh=221&hovw=228&tx=110&ty=129&page=1&tbnh=139&tbnw=148&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:4,s:0