# How to draw the default cursor image in JAVA

Tags: java, image, file, cursor

I'm trying to draw multiple cursors on a paint component in Java.
In order to do so, I will need to convert the default cursor into an image file.
any ideas as to how I can do this?

Comment: Try googling "cur to png"

Comment: I'm trying to convert the default cursor into an image file using java code. Not using third party software. Sorry for not making that clear enough

Comment: By the way this is an unsolved problem. Here is the same issue raised about 4 years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962271/how-to-capture-screen-image-with-mouse-pointer-on-it-in-java

Comment: I'm pretty confident that it can't be done...