# Mirror the computer screen in a Java application

Tags: java, windows-10, screen

I want to make a java application that mirrors the screen of a computer (with Windows 10) and shows it in itself. It's nothing too complex (I think): it's just an app that captures everything that is showed on the computer screen and shows it in itself. But I don't want to mirror the main screen. I want to mirror the secondary screen, the projected screen.

---> Reason why I need this:
I project contents on big screens in church which are almost 20 meters away from me and it's a bit hard to see the content, and there's no space to put another monitor next to mine... That's why I need an app that shows me in the main screen what is being exhibited.

I already searched about it on web and didn't find satisfactory results... The maximum I found was screenshot and literally record the screen and save as MP4 or another extension of your preference.

Someone could help me in this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, the idea is pretty simple.  You want to use an instance of `Robot` to capture a snapshot of the screen.

The first thing you need to do though, is get the "area" of the screen you want to capture and this is not as easy it as might sound as Java doesn't seem to provide the "screen names"  (on Windows `GraphicsDevice#getIDstring` might return the name, but on MacOS it didn't)

So, I started by trying to look at the screen resolutions and tried to figure out which screen I wanted...

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();
for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {
    System.out.println(gd.getDisplayMode());
}
```

I could have also used `getBounds` and tried to figure out where each screen was positioned, but what ever works.

Once you have this information, you can use `GraphicsDevice#getBounds` to get the physical area of the screen, which you can feed to `Robot`

Now, you need some way to produce and consume those snapshots.  You need to be aware of the fact that Swing is not thread safe and is single threaded.  This means you can't capture the snapshot from the Event Dispatching Thread and should not try to update the UI from outside of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

With this in mind, I decided to go with a `SwingWorker`.  It does most of the heavy lifting for us and provides a simplified workflow.  See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details.

Okay, the next issue to solve, is how to render the screen.  The basic concept is just to paint the image onto a component, which isn't that hard, the hard part is scaling the image.

There's been a lot of discussion on the subject, but you could take a look at [How do I resize images inside an application when the application window is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876615/how-do-i-resize-images-inside-an-application-when-the-application-window-is-resi/12876799#12876799) and [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

The first presents a concept of "scale to fit" and "scale to fill" algorithms and the second presents a better way to scale a image then using `Image#getScaledInstance` (which the example uses) as `getScaledInstance` doesn't always present the best result.  You could also take a look at [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java) which presents some more ideas and discussions.

[image: Or to easy]

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();
        for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {
            System.out.println(gd.getDisplayMode());
        }

        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private CaptureWorker worker;
        private BufferedImage snapshot;

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            startCapture();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            stopCapture();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        protected void startCapture() {
            try {
                stopCapture();
                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getScreenDevices()[0];
                worker = new CaptureWorker(gd, new CaptureWorker.Observer() {
                    @Override
                    public void imageAvaliable(CaptureWorker source, BufferedImage img) {
                        TestPane.this.snapshot = img;
                        repaint();
                    }
                });
                worker.execute();
            } catch (AWTException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        protected void stopCapture() {
            if (worker == null) {
                return;
            }
            worker.stop();
            worker = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (snapshot != null) {
                double scaleFactor = Math.min(1d, getScaleFactorToFill(new Dimension(snapshot.getWidth(), snapshot.getHeight()), getSize()));
                int scaleWidth = (int) Math.round(snapshot.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
                int scaleHeight = (int) Math.round(snapshot.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

                Image imageToRender = snapshot.getScaledInstance(scaleWidth, scaleHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                int x = (getWidth() - imageToRender.getWidth(this)) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - imageToRender.getHeight(this)) / 2;

                g2d.drawImage(imageToRender, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public double getScaleFactor(int iMasterSize, int iTargetSize) {
            double dScale = 1;
            dScale = (double) iTargetSize / (double) iMasterSize;

            return dScale;
        }

        public double getScaleFactorToFit(Dimension original, Dimension toFit) {
            double dScale = 1d;

            if (original != null && toFit != null) {
                double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(original.width, toFit.width);
                double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(original.height, toFit.height);

                dScale = Math.min(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);
            }
            return dScale;
        }

        public double getScaleFactorToFill(Dimension masterSize, Dimension targetSize) {
            double dScaleWidth = getScaleFactor(masterSize.width, targetSize.width);
            double dScaleHeight = getScaleFactor(masterSize.height, targetSize.height);

            double dScale = Math.max(dScaleHeight, dScaleWidth);

            return dScale;
        }

    }

    public class CaptureWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, BufferedImage> {

        public interface Observer {

            public void imageAvaliable(CaptureWorker source, BufferedImage img);
        }

        private AtomicBoolean keepRunning = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        private Robot bot;
        private Rectangle captureBounds;

        private final Duration interval = Duration.ofMillis(250);

        private Observer observer;

        public CaptureWorker(GraphicsDevice device, Observer observer) throws AWTException {
            captureBounds = device.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
            this.observer = observer;
            bot = new Robot();
        }

        public void stop() {
            keepRunning.set(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<BufferedImage> chunks) {
            BufferedImage img = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
            observer.imageAvaliable(this, img);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try {
                while (keepRunning.get()) {
                    Instant anchor = Instant.now();
                    System.out.println("Snapshot");
                    BufferedImage image = bot.createScreenCapture(captureBounds);
                    System.out.println("Pubish");
                    publish(image);
                    Duration duration = Duration.between(anchor, Instant.now());
                    System.out.println("Took " + duration.toMillis());
                    duration = duration.minus(interval);
                    System.out.println("Time remaining " + duration.toMillis());
                    if (duration.isNegative()) {
                        long sleepTime = Math.abs(duration.toMillis());
                        System.out.println("Sleep for " + sleepTime);
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

**Don't forget**

You need to know which screen you want to capture.  Take a look at the `startCapture` method, this where I configured the `CaptureWorker`.  I just grabbed the screen at index `0` and was lucky enough to get the screen I wanted

Also, this is unsupported.  This presents the "how to capture a screen and renderer it a window" portion of your question.  How you decide which screen or how you might present that information to the user to configure is all up to you

Comment: Wow! You already helped me a lot! But I still have some questions:

First, how to capture the cursor too?

Second, how to increase the FPS of the snapshots? I already tried changing the interval to smaller values of milliseconds. Currently, it's setted as 50 milliseconds, but I still don't get a satisfactory result... I also tried 1 millisecond (XD), but still the result it's not good (seems like nothing changes...), besides that the app, in this configuration, consumes too much CPU :-(

Comment: I don't know how to capture the mouse, might not be supported.  As to increasing the FPS, I noted that it takes between 25-30 milliseconds to grab a single snapshot, so you're only going to get around roughly 30fps

Comment: @VictorHugoSantosdeMoraes For mouse capture, you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962271/how-to-capture-screen-image-with-mouse-pointer-on-it-in-java

Comment: @VictorHugoSantosdeMoraes For faster screen capture, you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665529/faster-alternative-to-java-awt-robot-createscreencapture